# What does it mean to split by '\;' in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, split, delimiter

What does the \ in this code mean?
When I try splitting by just ';' I receive a 'java.lang.Exception: Results too large' error message.

`df.withColumn('split_col', split(col('field'), '\;'))`

I tried googling this but didn't find good search results.

Comment: A regexp in Java does not have a special meaning, so the `\` should not change anything. Could you please post the complete stacktrace and also your imports. Where does the `split` function really come from?